# How to ignore .svn folder when searching in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

How can I ignore .svn folders when searching in Total Commander?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- With Total Commander 8.01: *Configuration menu* / *Options* / *(Operation)* / *Ignore List*
- With older versions: *Configuration menu* / *Options* / *(Display)* / *Ignore List*

Then add

```
.svn
```

to the textbox.

Comment: This also excludes .svn folders when copying. This helps me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: You should be aware that this option also prevents .svn folder from being shown, in my case I don't want to hide any folders.

Answer (score 167):

To exclude some files or folders from your search, use the following syntax in "Search field:":

1. Exclude from search *.bak and *.old files

   ```
   my*.*|*.bak *.old
   ```
2. Don't search in .svn folders

   ```
   *.cs|.svn\
   ```
3. Don't search in .git folder

   ```
   *.cs|.git\
   ```

The meaning of `|` is: 'and not'. Everything after it is excluded from the search. This syntax can also be used in other places, for example inside the ignore list.

Comment: Is everything after `|` excluded, or should I use the character for every exclude?

Comment: Accepted answer address true need of OP, but this answer is pure gold. It work in "synchronize dirs" dialog too (and I suppose in every single place where file mask is needed).

Comment: This seems to require a wildcard * in the search item before the `|` in TC 8.50.

Comment: I think this approach is much more flexible than palacsint's answer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I tried search text, but exclude searching in directories bin and obj. I didn't know that pattern before pipe is required too, but I found help here:
https://gist.github.com/DStereo/af5f54c2d2d0d7073383f22753396185

So I had to put pattern in Search for field.

```
*|bin\ obj\
```

Answer (score 2):

In version 9.12 you should also use an asterix.
So add the following to *Configuration menu / Options / (Operation) / Ignore List*:

```
*.svn
```

Comment: This isn't required in version 10.